# PHP mail HTML formatting not working

Tags: php, html, function, email, html-email

I wrote a code to send PHP mail using HTML format.

```
  $email_message = '
        <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><div style="color: #3300FF; font-size: 18px;">text</div></tr></table></body></html>';

    $mail_to = 'xxx@xxxxxxxx.com'; 
    $mail_subject = 'Booking';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: <xxx@xxxxxx.com>';        
    mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

**but this output look like this:**

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div style="color: #3300FF; font-size: 18px;">
```

display all html code without formatting, could any one help me, I can't find the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting `$header` variable here

```
$headers = "From: <xxx@xxxxxx.com>";
```

That should be

```
$headers .= "From: <xxx@xxxxxx.com>";   // Add the concatenate operator
```

Answer (score 1):

the last line of the header i think your header  you forgot to concatenate

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: <xxx@xxxxxx.com>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @shankar pointed out, but I think thats not the issue because first variable should be initialise in order to concatenate it.

Here is the [link](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) for proper html email